# Wonky, off-axis rotation

Tags: animation

Based on what I have read so far, I'm the 3,600th person to ask this question, but every answer I have read (or have seen on youtube) thus far does not solve MY wonky rotation prob.

--Animation of rotating objects are constrained to global axis.  Got it.
--Creating an empty object and then parenting the object-in-need-of-rotation to the empty.  Got that too.
--Rotate the empty in animation to backdoor the issue.  Check.
--But somehow tilting the empty global axis to match my non-global axis of rotation?  While I can tilt the empty, the axis of rotation remains global.   I've tried it 40 different ways. I suck.  But a quitter I am not.

Comment: Could you add an image of your interface?

Comment: I got it sorted.  The key (or at least one of them) seems to be to FIRST animate your object on global, THEN parent to an empty, which you can rotate to whichever axis you desire.